# Automatic background removal from still image without user interaction

Tags: image-processing, machine-learning, computer-vision

I am trying to develop an image search application. I have crawled through e-commerce websites and obtained some data set of images(~2.5 Million). Now I want to identify the object of interest from each image so that when i do a feature comparison on large scale the results will be accurate(generally there is only one object of interest in each image). I went through grab cuts and graph cuts but that require user interaction of some sort. Is there any way where i can remove the user interaction aspect and do this automatically.

Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: You can look at something like [objectness](http://groups.inf.ed.ac.uk/calvin/Publications/alexe12pami.pdf) or other saliency measures, that will find what is likely to be an object in your image. If you have a uniform background the task can be accomplished more simply. Then you can mark the regions inside the object as (probably) foreground, and the regions outside as (probably) background, and run grub-cut.

Comment: Thanks Miki for the Info